# Stop a car without static friction

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, everyday-life, torque, drag

If we want to stop a car really fast, we must put on the brakes in a way as to maximize static friction. The brakes create dynamic friction between the axle and the wheel, which in turn creates a torque $T_{break}$. This torque will push on the ground which will create a static friction force $F_{staticfriction}$ that slows the translational movement of the vehicle.
The static friction force also causes a clockwise torque on the wheel $T_{staticfriction}$. So the total equation for the torque on the wheel is

$T_{net} = J\alpha = T_{break} - T_{staticfriction}$

I'm trying to theoretically figure out if we can stop a moving vehicle and its wheels without any static friction involved. I'm assuming no rolling resistance, the surface has friction and the wheel remains in contact with the surface the whole time. For example, could we maybe perfectly balance $T_{break}$ with air resistance acting on the vehicle as to eliminate $T_{staticfriction}$?

Basically, could we have $T_{break}$ without $T_{staticfriction}$?

This is unrealistic, I know, but I find it solidifies my understanding to imagine extreme cases like these.

Comment: So, what specifically what is your question? It’s unclear what you are asking

Comment: So basically, you're asking "can you stop a car with a parachute?"  To which the answer is basically yes, drag racers do it.

Comment: static friction would mean that the car is already stopped. You mean dynamic friction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction

Comment: @BobD What I'm asking is if we can apply the brakes on the car to stop the wheel but without any static friction appearing. Or does static friction appear as soon as we have any counter torque acting on the wheel?

Comment: @CortAmmon That's a good way to think about it. But when drag racers stop there is also a lot of static friction going on I believe. Here I'm talking about a hypothetical case where we brake so that no static friction appears between the ground and wheels, but the car still stops and the wheels still stops rotating eventually.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis Wrong. Static friction can and does act on a moving car if the car is accelerating. I'm assuming rolling condition, which means the contact point between the wheel and ground is instantaneously at rest, that's why we can talk about static friction.

Comment: Then you shouldn't refer to static friction in the brakes. Not only is your discussion vague. The only question is rhetorical.

Comment: Are you asking whether air resistance would stop a car in the absence of all other forces? That question does have an answer, although it is quite unrealistic as in practice other forces will dominate over air resistance as the car slows.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis Yes, I was unclear in my explanation. I'm not talking about static friction in the brakes. What I'm trying to say is that the brakes causes dynamic friction around the axle of the wheel. This dynamic friction in turn causes a counter-torque of the wheel which leads to static friction between the wheels and the ground.
My question is whether we can brake (have dynamic friction between axle and wheel) without causing static friction between wheel and ground?

Comment: @CharlesFrancis
There are two questions, one of which is rhetoric.
And yes this is completely unrealistic.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm asking is if we can apply the brakes on the car to stop the
>   wheel but without any static friction appearing.

No.

> Or does static
>   friction appear as soon as we have any counter torque acting on the
>   wheel?

Yes.

Per Newton's third law, a static friction force will be exerted by the road on the tires as soon as there is a counter torque acting on the wheel due to braking.

That static friction force, along with any other dissipative (heat producing) forces such as air resistance, normal kinetic friction between moving parts, and of course the kinetic friction at the brake pads themselves, will bring the vehicle to a stop.

Even without braking, the dissipative forces will eventually bring the vehicle to a stop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps. Okay, so no counter torque without static friction. This should also mean that it's theoretically impossible to completely stop (zero translational movement and zero wheel rotation)  a moving car without static friction? I'm assuming 
the ground is not frictionless and the wheel must touch the ground.

Comment: Actually it’s the other way around. Without torque applied to the wheel  there is no static friction. It prevents relative motion between the surfaces.Static friction force exists in opposition to another force. Static friction acts forward with clockwise torque enablingvthe cars acceleration. It acts backwards when torque is counterclockwise and is responsible for deceleration.if the ground is frictionless it skids

Comment: @user2251965 What made you "un accept" my answer?

Comment: Because after asking a similar question, I found out it is actually possible to balance the wind force and brake force in a way to stop the car while the total static friction remains at 0 the whole time. I will see if I can write my own answer here.

Comment: @user2251965 But the braking force IS a static friction force. Something doesn't sound right. Can you give me a link to your other question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/549650/stopping-a-car-while-static-friction-remains-zero

Comment: I don't think your answer is wrong, but it's not answering what I'm after. Partly my fault because I formulated myself in a bad way.

Comment: @user2251965 I looked at the link. The "answer" (and there wasn't an answer, just comments by Aaron Stevens) talks about a car on ice with air resistance. You can not cause the vehicle to stop by applying the brakes if there is no static friction to enable the brakes to decelerate the car. So it is inappropriate to talk about "braking" under such conditions because the brakes don't matter (assuming ice is "frictionless").So my answer to your question here, as posed, should still be acceptable.  If you had something else in  mind, it should be a separate question. Anyway, its your prerogative.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just feel like I wasted my time

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. I still find your answer and discussion useful.
The brakes still matter because they stop the wheels' rotation. But maybe it's inappropriate of me to see the motion of the car as both being the translational motion of the car, and the wheels' rotation.

Comment: @user2251965 They may stop the wheel from rotating, but they don't stop the car. The title of your post was "Stop a car without static friction". Not stop the wheels from rotating. Anyway, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: A post is more than its title. I can't fit all the details into the title. For me stopping a car means stopping its translational motion and the rotation of the wheels. But it was wrong of me to assume that everyone thinks this way. I should have explained myself better. But since I have linked to my other question now and we have discussed it, I will accept your answer again.

Comment: @user2251965 Thank you for your reconsideration.